# How to remove certain characters in a string in blade template

Tags: laravel

I would like to know how to remove certain characters in a string inside blade templade, say:

the string is `my string_345432.pdf` and you just want to remove the number part `_345432` and left with `my string.pdf`

Comment: Have you tried something? or do we have to code for you ? take a look at substr() , strpos(), rtrim() and str_replace(), You will get there...

Comment: or preg_replace()...

Comment: I have tried to use truncate function, but preg_replace works perfectly.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should do it in controller, not in template.

You can use regex for that something like this:

```
preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z.]/', '', $string);
```

If you're really need it to use in blade template, you can create some additional file with helper function, and use it anywhere you want:

```
function filterFileName($string) {
    return preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z.]/', '', $string);
}
```

1. Create helpers.php file
2. Add your function filterFileName in it.
3. Add that file in composer.json and load it with composer dump-autoload
4. Now, you can use it in template:

```
{{ filterFileName($string) }}
```